# What's causing undefined index error?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php 
  mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
  mysql_select_db("sample") or die("database could not connect "); 
?> 
<html> 
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Php Code for View, Search, Edit and Delete 
Record" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<title>View Student  Record</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1><u>Student Database</u></h1></center>
<?php
  $roll=$_GET["roll"]; 
  $query="select * from student where roll='$roll'"; 
  $result=mysql_query($query);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
  }
?>
<table style=" border:1px solid silver" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0px" 
align="center" border="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="4" style="background:#0066FF; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:20px">VIEW 
STUDENT DATABASE</td></tr>
<tr>
<td> Roll Number</td><td><? echo $row[0];?></td> 
<td> Class</td><td><? echo $row[1];?></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Name of Student</td><td><? echo $row[2];?></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sex</td><td><? echo $row[3];?></td> 
<td>Address1</td><td><? echo $row[4];?></td></tr>
<tr> 
<td>Address2</td><td><? echo $row[5];?></td> 
<td>Address3</td><td><? echo $row[6];?></td></tr> 
<tr>
<td>Remarks</td><td><? echo $row[7];?></td></tr> 
<tr>
</table>
<p align="center"><a href="index.php">Go Back to Home</a></p> 
</body>
</html>
```

that is my code

```
<?php 
  $roll=$_GET["roll"]; 
  $query="select * from student where roll='$roll'";
  $result=mysql_query($query);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  }
?>
```

Here's my problem. I don't know how to get rid of this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: roll in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\view.php on line 16

Line 16 is `$roll=$_GET["roll"];`.

This code should display the information in each row, but as I run it, it shows nothing.

Comment: I believe you can set error_reporting(0); which means no errors at all or error_reporting(4); 

or you can put it in an if statement

if(isset($_GET['roll']){
$roll=$_GET["roll"]; 
$query="select * from student where roll='$roll'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   }

}

Comment: Remove the whole php. You're doing nothing in the while loop anyway...

Comment: You should put isset to check $_GET["roll"]; contains any value, if not do something else, currently your $_GET["roll"]; is null therefore the error undefined index came out.

Comment: @Phil It will be `false` after the loop, so the `echo`s won't work either.

Comment: @Phil You made me throw away my draft reply! :)

Comment: @Adam I find that indentation pattern a little unorthodox, but nice edit on the last part.

Comment: I probably should've indented the HTML, too. Oh, well. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is an undefined `$_GET` index. Use `isset()`, eg

```
$roll = isset($_GET['roll']) ? $_GET['roll'] : null; // or a suitable default
```

Try something like this to fix your query loop

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
?>

<table style=" border:1px solid silver" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0px" align="center" border="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="4" style="background:#0066FF; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:20px">VIEW 
STUDENT DATABASE</td></tr>

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) : ?>

<!-- rows, cells and echos, etc -->

<?php endwhile ?>

</table>
```

And finally, the MySQL extension is now deprecated. I strongly recommend you switch to [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Using [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) would also solve your SQL injection vulnerability in `mysql_query()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you pass `roll` on the querystring**. Without that, none of your PHP code makes sense. You're getting data from MySql based on `$roll` and trying to display it; if there's no value on that variable, there's no data. So add `isset` as Phil suggested, and dot run **any** PHP if it's not set.

Also, get rid of the `while` loop, and only execute `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)` once, and only if `isset($_GET['roll'])`. Otherwise, you'll try to echo `false` later on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code below `$roll=$_GET["roll"];`

```
if (isset($_GET["roll"))
{
// IF TRUE, DO THE QUERY ECHO YOUR RESULT
}

?>
```